# Restful web service xml update

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest, glassfish

I have a restful web service created on netbeans and connected to a database. when I start and deploy the web Service, it works great and returns the right information, but if I do any update in the database the xml content don't update, it just still returning xml with the old content.
To return the updated content I need to redeploy the web service. 
Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: Sounds like the response XML is not read from database, could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all, isolate if the data on the DB gets updated by running a query. If it fails you might need to make sure that you're committing the data properly.

If the data is properly stored, you might have cache issues. Please post some sample code of your application  so that we can provide deeper insights (controller and service layer).